# Div that acts as file upload?

Tags: javascript, php

I simply want to make an upload or something like browse on the div itself like act as a file input and trigger its function but my problem was i'm new to java script and quite embarrassed myself for brainstorming for almost an hour and looking for the same problem on the internet.

So i don't have any other choice but to ask question here

my code

```js
 <script type="">
     
    $('#pic1').click(function (Upload) {
       $('#fileToUpload').click();
    });
    
    </script>
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pic1" style="border:1px solid white;width:200px;height:150px;float:left;margin:10px;" onclick="Upload">
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" size="1" style="display:none;">
         
    
        </div>


<br> while my file input is hidden inside the div<br>
```

Comment: you most likely need a `<form>` for this to have any chance

Comment: yes i do have a form wait i'll update my post

Comment: <form id="test_form" method="GET" action="">

Comment: to upload a file, you'll need the method to be POST

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    
    var readURL = function(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
    
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    

    $(".file-upload").on('change', function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    
    $(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
       $(".file-upload").click();
    });
});
```

```css
.upload-button {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.profile-pic {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: block;
}

.file-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" />
<div class="upload-button">Upload Image</div>
<input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
```

This code snippet is specific for images where its specified like this `accept="image/*"/`

Comment: tnx this one perfectly works fine and easy to understand

Comment: @RaymartCalinao glad to hear that my answer helped you!

Comment: very glad you answer my question and also for arranging my lazy css hahaha

Comment: You can use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of reading it as base64

Answer (score 5):

You just have to put input inside the `label`.

Try following snippet.

```css
input[type=file] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id="test_form" method="GET" action="">
  <label id="pic1">
    Upload Picture
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" size="1" />


  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
#pic1{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
}   
</style>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="pic1">Upload</div>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="display:none;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pic1').click(function(){ 
    $('#fileToUpload').trigger('click'); 
});
</script>
```